# how to use sort function of algorithm (c++)

Tags: c++

everyone
I want to sort vector of basefile objects.
I have 2 classes which inherit from bsefile called file and directory, and each has fields of name and size.
I want to sort the vector by name, and I tried to do this with the sort function of algorithm library,  but for some reason the vector printing does not appear sorted.
I attach a code for the print and send to the sorting function, can you tell me if i use them properly?

sort function -

```
    void Directory::sortByName(){
        vector<BaseFile*> vecToSortByName = this->getChildren();
        sort(vecToSortByName.begin(), vecToSortByName.end() , [](BaseFile* &left, BaseFile* &right){
            return ( left->getName() < right->getName() );
        });
    }



void printForLs(bool sortBySize ,  Directory* mkdirPath){
    if(sortBySize){ //if -s in the command
        mkdirPath->sortBySize();  //we sort stable sort
    }else mkdirPath->sortByName(); //else we need to sort only by name
    vector<BaseFile*> list = mkdirPath->getChildren();
    int size = list.size();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        list[i]->printMyType();
        cout << "  " <<list[i]->getName() << "  " << list[i]->getSize() << endl ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with something simpler. Look it up on the Internet. Gradually complexify your tries and converge to your use case. SO won't write your home work for you ;)

Comment: @YSC actually, I find that quite often someone on SO will.

Comment: @UKMonkey I made the vow to ignore every comment starting with "actually...", but yes you're right.

Comment: @YSC sorry to correct you - both because I don't like being 'that guy' and also because I wish your comment was correct!

Comment: @UKMonkey well, my last comment was meant to be a joke, not a rant ;)

Answer (score 2):

With the initialization here

```
vector<BaseFile*> vecToSortByName = this->getChildren();
```

you *copy* the vector. You then sort this copy, and throw it away (as it gets destructed when the function returns).

You either need to save this copy, or use references.